# Root Inline Box - Can an root inline box have descendants in turn or what does that mean?

Tags: html, css, text, layout

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-inline-3/#root-inline-box

> The block container also generates a root inline box, which is an
> anonymous inline box that holds all of its inline-level contents.
> (Thus, all text in an inline formatting context is directly contained
> by an inline box, whether the root inline box or **one of its
> descendants**.) The root inline box inherits from its parent block
> container, but is otherwise unstyleable.

What does "one of his descendants" refer to?

Can an root inline box **have descendants in turn** or what does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose we have this mark-up

```html
<div>
  In the case of <strong>Fire</strong>, break glass to 
  <span>sound alarm. <img src="bell.jpg" alt="bell symbol"></span>
</div>
```

This will generate a [box tree](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#box-tree). [image: Box tree showing block container box, root inline box, 3 descendant boxes and four text runs.]

"Fire" and "sound alarm" are contained within boxes that are descendants of the root inline box, while "In the case of " and " break glass to " are contained directly by the root inline box.

Comment: hi @Alohci, excellent +1. This box tree is when we have *inline layout*, right?, that is, when a block container has pure **inline-level content**, right? https://www.w3.org/TR/css-inline-3/#model

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: hi @Alohci +1. an `inline-block` element itself (something that is not an **inline box**) could be contained directly in the `root inline box` or in one of its descendant boxes, but the content of an `inline-block` would be in a **different formatting context**, right?

Comment: @Coder23 - That's correct. The inline-block box establishes a new formatting context for its content.

Comment: Excellent @Alohci +1. I have asked a question before, could you please help me with it. It is related to this question I just asked you, you would gladly have my +1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75909339/formatting-context-and-atomic-inline-level-boxes

Comment: Is this box tree also the same if instead of a block container it is an inline element, e.g. a `span`? @Alohci

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer - No the box tree will be different. For one thing, the box created by an inline element can never have a root inline box as a child.