# Formatting context and atomic inline-level boxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox, w3c

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#inline-boxes

> An inline box is one that is both inline-level and whose contents
> participate in its containing inline formatting context. A
> non-replaced element with a 'display' value of 'inline' generates an
> inline box. Inline-level boxes that are not inline boxes (such as
> replaced inline-level elements, inline-block elements, and
> inline-table elements) are called atomic inline-level boxes because
> **they participate in their inline formatting context as a single opaque
> box**.

This means that an inline-level atomic box is an *inline-level* box that generates a formatting context (a layout) **different from the inline formatting context (inline layout)**, e.g., an `inline-flex` (**flex layout**) right?

I'm not sure if I understand the concept well, hence the question

Answer (score 1):

Well, a few points.

First, not *all* atomic inline-level boxes generate a formatting context for their contents. Specifically, replaced inline-level elements (img, canvas, video, etc) don't.

Second, while apart from the above, inline-level atomic boxes *do* always generate an independent formatting context for their content (i.e. one different from the inline formatting context that they themselves are participating in), I don't think you can infer that from the paragraph you quote. That is more describing its display-outside behaviour. For example, that it has separate rules about how it impacts the line-box height that it's in, and that it is not fragmentable (i.e can't be broken, across lines). What happens inside that opaque box is defined elsewhere.

Finally, it's worth noting that non-atomic inline-level boxes can also establish formatting contexts, although not independent ones. For example, `display:ruby` establishes a ruby formatting context.